# OpenMP reductions inside subgrograms

Tags: fortran, openmp, reduction

The following Fortran code fails (random result), but replacing the call to mysum by abc=abc+1
gives the correct result. How to make OpenMP recognizing the reduction in a subprogram?

```
  program reduc

    use omp_lib
    implicit none

    integer :: abc=0, icount
    call OMP_set_num_threads(8)

    !$omp parallel private (icount) reduction(+:abc)
    !$omp do

    do icount = 1,8
      !abc = abc + 1
      call mysum(OMP_get_thread_num())
    end do

    !$omp end do
    !$omp end parallel
    print*,"abc at end: ",abc

    contains

    subroutine mysum(omp_rank)

    integer :: omp_rank

      abc = abc + 1
      print*,"OMP rank: ", omp_rank, " abc: ", abc

    endsubroutine mysum

  end program reduc
```

I also tried to put !$omp threadprivate (abc) into mysum, which was rejected with
"Error: Symbol 'abc' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type.", which is of course not true.

Comment: "Symbol 'abc' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type." is very true given the `implicit none` in force in `mysum`. The compiler is complaining, arguably with an unclear message, because `abc` is not a variable declared in `mysum` but in its host. `threadprivate` cannot apply to a variable from another scoping unit, so it is taken as though a local variable `abc` is being referenced (and such an `abc` would be implicitly typed).

Comment: Usually a reduction operates on a vector/array/matrix, and not a single element. So it would probably be elegant to send the reference for abc along with num_threads, have it as intent (IN), dimension(:), and have the OMP stuff in the function that returns the sum of abc. You cannot really reduce a single element, to the sum of the single element, as it is already the same as the single element… and hence nothing to be done.

Comment: @Homlz Of course one can reduce a single element, and this is quite common to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the reduction, the original variable `abc` is privatised in each thread, but `abc` in the contained subroutine always refers to the original, non privatised variable.

The solution is to pass it as an argument:

```
subroutine mysum(omp_rank,abc)
    integer, intent(in) :: omp_rank
    integer, intent(inout) :: abc
    
    abc = abc + 1
    print*,"OMP rank: ", omp_rank, " abc: ", abc
endsubroutine mysum
```

Comment: Yet another reason to dislike host association.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, I can't employ it as we are dealing with the guts of a big project. - Good to have learnt though about a major flaw of OpenMP: Inability to handle global variables uniformly across scopes (thus also files) when it comes to thread privatisation. Hopefully this will be improved in the future.

Comment: @MRheinhardt This is definitely not a flaw in OpenMP: to make it work the way you would like, the compiler would have to generate different binary codes for `mysub()` depending on where it is called from. This would be possible and not too complicated for a contained routine by analysing the calls in the parent routines, but it would be extremely tricky or even impossible for routines in different files/units.